# Python: variable "tricking" try-exception, but works for if statement

Tags: python, parsing, exception, if-statement

I know the title seems crazy, but it is true.  Here is my predicament.  First, I am still a beginner at Python so please be considerate.  I am trying to test if a variable exists.  Now the variable comes from a file that is parsed in yaml.  Whenever I try this code,

```
if not name['foo']:
    print "No name given."
    return False
```

Python does as you would expect and returns false. However, when I try to change it to this code,

```
try:
    name['foo']
except:
    print "ERROR: No name given."
    raise
```

the exception is never risen.  I have searched and searched and could not find any questions or sites that could explain this to me.  My only thought is that the parser is "tricking" the exception handler, but that doesn't really make sense to me.

I have made sure that there were no white spaces in the name field of the document I am parsing.  The field has the format:

```
*name: foo
*ver: bar
```

Like I have said, I made sure that foo was completely deleted along with any whitespace between lines.  If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

And I apologize for the negative logic in the if statement.  The function has to go through a series of checks.  The best way I could think of to make sure all the checks were executed was to return true at the very end and to return false if any individual check failed.

Comment: "Python does as you would expect and returns false". If `name` is an ordinary dict, and `"foo"` isn't a key in that dict, I wouldn't expect it to return false. I'd expect a `KeyError`. You ought to use `if "foo" not in name` if you want to check for the existence of a key.

Comment: Why would you expect it to return false in an `if` and throw an exception on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- That shouldn't throw an exception! You're doing `name['foo']` in two places and expecting different behavior.
- The `name` doesn't behave like a dictionary, if it did you would NOT get a return of `False` in the first example, you'd get an exception. Try doing this:

  ```
  name = {}
  name['foo']
  ```

  Then you'll get a `KeyError` exception
- Don't ever have an `except:` block! Always catch the specific exception you're after, like `IndexError` or whatever

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I read your first bullet I knew exactly what I did.  I feel so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think it would raise an exception. The key evidently exists, otherwise the first snippet would not work. The value for that key is obviously some false-y value like `False`, `None`, `[]` or `''`.

Answer (score 0):

> Python does as you would expect and returns false.

The exception (`KeyError`) will be thrown only if there is no key in a dictionary (assuming `name` is a dictionary). If you do

```
if not name['foo']:
```

and it does not throw an exception, then it means that `"foo"` is in `name` but the value evaluates to boolean false (it can be `False`, `None`, empty string `""`, empty list `[]`, empty dictionary `{}`,  some custom object, etc. etc.). Thus wrapping `name['foo']` with `try:except:` is pointless - the key is there.